# Best practice approach for scrollable control in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls, scrollable

I am designing a windows forms control for Syntax Editing. I know there are already a lot out there, like [Scintilla](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/), [FastColoredTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting), [Actipro Syntax Edito](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/windowsforms/syntaxeditor)r, [Avalon Edit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit) etc. I have reasons for designing my own, so that's not the issue.

So far I have been designing the look and feel of the control. It will need to be able to control vertically, and horizontally.

**The options I have come across are:**

1. My control extends [ScrollableControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.aspx) or [ContainerControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.aspx)
2. My control instantiates a [HScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.hscrollbar.aspx) and [VScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.vscrollbar.aspx) control and places them accordingly
3. My control uses [ScrollBarRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbarrenderer.aspx) to custom draw the scrollbars

I am not sure which of these options would be best practice for my control.

I tried using [ScrollableControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.aspx) and [ContainerControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.aspx), but this had some very undesired results, probably because the controls `DisplayRectangle` was scrolling...I don't want this. I want to scroll a custom drawn rectangle which holds the text.

I tried instantiating HScrollBar and VScrollBar, but this seemed very buggy, and didn't work well with focus and I couldn't work out how to properly capture VScroll and HScroll events.

I tried using [ScrollBarRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbarrenderer.aspx), but this seems like a hell of a lot of effort just to implement a scrollbar, and with this approach, I would still have to capture and handle the events appropriately.

So which of these approaches should I be using, or indeed an approach I may have overlooked?

Comment: You are getting stuck early, the next 41 problems are much harder to solve.  A scrollbar doesn't actually scroll anything, it just tells you where to start drawing.

Comment: Wheel inventors are the **best**!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ScrollBarRenderer is only used to draw a scrollbar, it doesn't actually perform any scroll calculations nor actions.

Personally, I find the HScrollBar and VScrollBar rather clumsy controls to work.

Inheriting from the ScrollableControl (or Panel to get a built-in windows control border) is probably the easiest.  You use the AutoScrollMinSize property to set the size of the interior surface, and then perform a TranslateTransform on the graphics object using the AutoScrollPosition property to handle the "where" to draw part of the control:

```
public class ScrollControl : ScrollableControl {

  public ScrollControl() {
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(0, 600);
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e);

    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X, 
                                  this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(16, 32, 64, 32));
  }
}
```

Be careful though, a syntax text editor is a different beast that a drawing control.  I would advise using a RichTextBox control for that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'd certainly never explored the TranslateTransform method before...so I shall play around with it. In terms of using a RichTextBox, I have already seen many implementations which use this, but they are all really slow when you get to a reasonable file size (say 1000 lines). Plus, a RichTextBox does not support line numbers, visual cues, code folding etc, which are all features I intend to implement. I know there are some out there like Scintilla, but even these are lacking in some respects!