# C# UserControl scrollbar issues

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, scrollbar

I'm having trouble setting the `VerticalScroll/HorizontalScroll.Value` property. Every time I set the value, the scrollbar moves, then snaps back (see screenshot below)

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code for my user control:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyGanttChart
{
    public class Chart : UserControl
    {
        public Chart()
        {
            HorizontalScroll.Visible = true;
            VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseWheel(e);

            ScrollEventType scrollType = ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement;
            if (e.Delta > 0)
                scrollType = ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement;

            ScrollOrientation orientation = ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll;
            if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
                orientation = ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll;

            ScrollEventArgs args = new ScrollEventArgs(scrollType, 1, orientation);
            OnScroll(args);
        }

        protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
        {
            base.OnScroll(se);

            if (se.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
            {
                //if (se.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement || se.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement)
                //    X -= HorizontalScroll.LargeChange; // se.NewValue;
                //else if (se.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement || se.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement)
                //    X += HorizontalScroll.LargeChange;

                if ((se.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement || se.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement) &&
                    HorizontalScroll.Value + HorizontalScroll.LargeChange <= HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
                {
                    HorizontalScroll.Value += HorizontalScroll.LargeChange;
                }
                else if ((se.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement || se.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement) &&
                    HorizontalScroll.Value - HorizontalScroll.LargeChange >= HorizontalScroll.Minimum)
                {
                    HorizontalScroll.Value -= HorizontalScroll.LargeChange;
                }
            }
            else if (se.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
            {
                //if (se.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement || se.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement)
                //    Y -= VerticalScroll.LargeChange;
                //else if (se.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement || se.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement)
                //    Y += VerticalScroll.LargeChange;

                if ((se.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement || se.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement) &&
                    VerticalScroll.Value + VerticalScroll.LargeChange <= VerticalScroll.Maximum)
                {
                    VerticalScroll.Value += VerticalScroll.LargeChange;
                }
                else if ((se.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement || se.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement) &&
                    VerticalScroll.Value - VerticalScroll.LargeChange >= VerticalScroll.Minimum)
                {
                    VerticalScroll.Value -= VerticalScroll.LargeChange;
                }
            }

            this.Invalidate(); //Force the control to redraw
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            if (!this.DesignMode)
                Draw(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle);
        }

        public float X = 0;
        public float Y = 0;

        private void Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rect)
        {
            graphics.TranslateTransform(X, Y);
            graphics.Clear(Color.White);

            Point center = new Point(rect.X + rect.Width / 2, rect.Y + rect.Height / 2);
            graphics.DrawString("hi", this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), center.X, center.Y, new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center});

            graphics.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

*(The control view currently does not move - I had that working with the `X` and `Y` values, but I'm working on the scrollbar values right now)*

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757408/c-sharp-usercontrol-verticalscroll-value-not-being-set) question but setting the value twice or calling `PerformLayout()` does not seem to work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: OnScroll means scrolling happened.  Then you change the scroll value, firing the OnScroll event again, etc, etc.  Don't do that.

Comment: Is it a requirement to do the scrolling on low level? You could let the container manage the scrolling with no code at all, and painting in a child panel with dimensions larger than the parent. This would avoid repainting your thing over and over.

Comment: @LarsTech I thought about that, but the `OnScroll` event is not being fired twice

Comment: @M.Parent How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What happens when you debug it?  Scrolling is built in, so I'm not sure why you need this code.

Comment: If I debug the `OnScroll` method always starts with the scrollbar being at 0 and ends with the scrollbar at 10 (every time I click the scroll button). The `OnPaint` method also ends with the scrollbar at 10. I'm not sure how to utilize "built in scrolling" because if I draw something to the graphics that is larger than the control's rectangle (and comment out my `OnScroll` override), the scrollbars don't do anything

Comment: Remove your code in the constructor and add `this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(1028, 1028);` or whatever size you want your canvas to be.  Comment out your scroll code, too.

Comment: You could also **not** use the UC surface as the canvas and instead use a Panel (possibly a custom control built with some styles useful when drawin), so you can expand the panel/canvas as needed and the scrollbars will follow.

Comment: @LarsTech That seems to do something weird https://i.imgur.com/EEL8Tuq.gifv Maybe something with how I'm painting?

Comment: Painting is a different issue.  See this [Best practice approach for scrollable control in C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14401135/719186)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see of your code, you don't need any custom code to manage the scrolling of your drawing.

First, you need to add a child panel inside your usercontrol which will be the container of the drawing. So you move the drawing code to this panel. You must ensure that this panel will resize itself if the drawing needs to be bigger. This is what will show the scrollbars on the usercontrol.

Second, you must set the AutoScroll property of your usercontrol to True. Doing so will ensure that any child control having a size or a position exceeding the usercontrol size can be scrolled. Have a look at the AutoScrollMargin property too. This is done automagically by the framework, so no other code is needed. Isn't it beautiful?

Finally, you can remove the two scrollbars you added.

Edit:
Moreover, when you draw, you don't need to compensate for the scrolling position. You just draw with origin 0,0 without taking care of the scroll. In addition, doing it this way will prevent any flickering caused by constantly redrawing.